# Custom aspx workflow form problem in WSPBuilder project

Tags: sharepoint, wspbuilder

I have a working wss3.0 + workflow solution, with some aspx forms (followed Robert Shelton’s tutorial)  and some document libraries. I would like to deploy it  with WSPBuilder but I have stuck hopeless.

The transformation of the workflow was 5 minutes, but I cannot transform workflow-forms at all. I have tried every way I found, but symptoms are constantly same:

The compiler at the codebehind file says “The name 'myAspxTextControl’ does not exist in the current context” for every controls defined in the aspx file.

I tired to connect them on the following ways:

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs"

```
     Inherits="SWEF_WSP.Test, SWEF_WSP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c935c51f6d8e9562" %>
```

Where SWEF_WSP.dll is my WSPBuilder projects assembly, SWEF_SWP is the namespace, Test.aspx and Test.aspx.cs are my form files demonstrating the issue.

I tried it with and without Codebehind field, and using separate @Asssembly directive too, and changed the the place of these files (in the Layout folder in 12 hive or not ), together, or not, the error is same.

I followed the

http://www.greggalipeau.com/2008/05/23/moving-a-sharepoint-workflow-between-solutions/

(and some more)

But unfortunately didn’t find any buildable example.

I must miss something very evident,

Any help would be greatly appreciated ...‎

---

bts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the .designer.cs file for the page - Visual studio won't generate it since the project is a workflow, not a website.

Comment: Put forms, to an web application inside the WSPBuilder Solution, generate the missing x.designer.cs  by right click on the x.aspx file, and sending the signed assembly to the GAC folder in the WSPBuilder deployment project. But I still have to copy the x.aspx file into the Layout folder. Any idea ?

Comment: Yes, you will still need to have the aspx file somewhere appropriate on the server - only the .cs files get compiled into the assembly. By layout folder, do you mean the one in your project? You certainly shouldn't need to copy anything to the server layouts folder manually.